# jBPM process is never exported into jar with Build & Deploy (KIE workbench 6.5.0)

Tags: drools, jbpm, kie-workbench, drools-kie-workbench

I am working on a project in which I have defined a simple jBPM process.
When I try to Build & Deploy this project the generated (k)jar seems correct but the defined business process is never exported: I need to include it manually by dropping it into the jar.

What is needed to to build, export and deploy a business process in KIE workbench?

The org.drools and org.jbpm were included at some time just to find out if that would force a succesful exportation of my business process, but it did not. Perhaps I need to include another build plugin, but according to documentation the current one should be sufficient.

I am working on a Wildfly 10.

The build log in console:

```
09:27:09,084 INFO  [org.guvnor.common.services.builder.ResourceChangeIncrementalBuilder] (Thread-154) Incremental build request received for: default://master@myRepository/myProject/src/main/resources/META-INF/kmodule.xml (updated).
09:27:09,224 INFO  [org.guvnor.common.services.builder.ResourceChangeIncrementalBuilder] (EJB default - 8) Incremental build request being processed: PathImpl{uri='default://master@myRepository/myProject', fileName='myProject', attrs={}} (updated).
09:27:10,697 WARN  [org.drools.compiler.kie.builder.impl.AbstractKieModule] (EJB default - 8) No files found for KieBase default
09:27:10,698 INFO  [org.drools.compiler.kie.builder.impl.KieRepositoryImpl] (EJB default - 8) KieModule was added: MemoryKieModule[releaseId=myOrganization:myProject:1.0.0-SNAPSHOT]
09:27:11,724 INFO  [AssetMgmt] (default task-33) Auto approve for user: Drools
09:27:11,725 INFO  [AssetMgmt] (default task-33) Operation : Build and deploy project
09:27:11,725 INFO  [AssetMgmt] (default task-33) Repository : myRepository/myProject
09:27:11,725 INFO  [AssetMgmt] (default task-33) Project : null
09:27:11,734 INFO  [org.guvnor.asset.management.backend.handlers.AssetMgmtStartWorkItemHandler] (default task-33) Start asset management process: BuildProject
09:27:13,311 WARN  [org.drools.compiler.kie.builder.impl.AbstractKieModule] (EJB default - 2) No files found for KieBase default
09:27:13,311 INFO  [org.drools.compiler.kie.builder.impl.KieRepositoryImpl] (EJB default - 2) KieModule was added: MemoryKieModule[releaseId=myOrganization:myProject:1.0.0-SNAPSHOT]
09:27:19,316 WARN  [org.drools.compiler.kie.builder.impl.AbstractKieModule] (EJB default - 4) No files found for KieBase default
09:27:19,317 INFO  [org.drools.compiler.kie.builder.impl.KieRepositoryImpl] (EJB default - 4) KieModule was added: MemoryKieModule[releaseId=myOrganization:myProject:1.0.0-SNAPSHOT]
09:27:23,176 INFO  [stdout] (EJB default - 4) Deploy of myOrganization:myProject:1.0.0-SNAPSHOT into runtime is skipped
```

Many thanks in advance.

This question is also exposed on the jBPM usage forum.

Code source is available on [github](https://github.com/eggsandbutter/kieworkbench).
Maven build kjar is available on [github](https://github.com/eggsandbutter/kieworkbench-maven).

EDITS: 
- I removed the code of my pom.xml since it is now available on GitHub.
- I can only post a maximum of two links, so I removed the link to the isue on the jBPM usage forum.
- I included the log output of the build.

Comment: If kjar is build successfully then all the processes and rules should be included in it. Are you building kjar from command line or through kie-workbench ? Can you share sample project with us ?

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer! I do everything within the KIE Workbench. I have provided more information and I have made the project and its kjar available on GitHub.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have encountered the error.
The error is that the process contained a rule task without assigning a ruleflow-group. This error was not detected during building & deploying but I detected it by coincidence in the console of Wildfly. Once I assigned a ruleflow-group to the task the process was exported. 
I think this error should be elevated to the workbench messages since the user is not alarmed.
I updated the projects on GitHub.
Thank you.